# Receive zero-status information from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I put a where(in when) to display information whose status is zero, but when I set it to zero, it takes all the information from the database and displays it.

```
Card::when($this->status, function ($query){
                    $query->where('status', 0);
                         })
                ->search(trim($this->search))
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->get();
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the data type for the `status` column?

Comment: @ceejayoz `tinyint`

Comment: keep in mind `when` receives `true` or `false` as its first args if `true` it process the callback otherwise not

Comment: I have 3 modes (approved - rejected and awaiting approval) and I used ‍`when` to filter the information.
What should I do now? Is there a solution? @Pradeep

Comment: do you want filter based on mode?

Comment: yes for mode @Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this : assuming `mode` is a column name

```
Card::when(in_array(request()->mode,['rejected','approved','approval']), function ($query){
              $query->where('mode', request()->mode);
          })
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')       
             ->get();
```

For more : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-when

Comment: glad it helps you happy coding

Comment: pls don't forget to upvote the answer also thanks